# I Can't get a DropDownList to populate from table. EF and MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, selectlist

I believe this will create a list in my HomeController. But not sure what calls it or where it goes in the Controller beside maybe the first Add ActionResult (GET method).

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items()
    {

        using (oesacEntities_compact db = new oesacEntities_compact())
        {
            var query = from s in db.tblSponsors select new { s.SponsorID, s.BizName };

            return query.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value=x.SponsorID.ToString(),
                    Text = x.BizName
                }).ToList();
        }

    }
```

I can't seem to send it to the Add view or to reference it from the Add view:

```
<div class="editor=field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SponsorID,IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectList);   
</div>
```

It seems so simple in other coding languages. I want to populate a pulldown with about 200 sponsor ID's for value, BizNames for text. For now at least. God help me after that when I want to show an Edit view with the value selected.
thankyou stackoverflow

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having? "It doesn't work" is not a valid thing to add to your question here. You _must_ provide error messages. Your first issue I can see is that the second argument to `DropDownListFor` must be `yourClass.items()` ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `SelectList` to your view. Ideally your view model should include a property for the `SelectList` but you can (yuk) use ViewBag, for example

View Model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public int SponsorID { get; set; }
  // other properties
  public SelectList SponsorList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult SomeThing()
{
  MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
  // assign the select list
  var sponsors = from s in db.tblSponsors;
  model.SponsorList = new SelecList(sponsors, "SponsorID", "BizName");
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SponsorID, Model.SponsorList);
```

or if you assigned the select list to ViewBag

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SponsorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.SponsorList);
```

Comment: I'm at a loss of how to create the select list.
    "model.SponsorList = // your code to create the select list"

All I am trying to do is make this a pulldown of choices on an add record view:
    SELECT SponsorID, BizName FROM tblSponsors

Comment: @JustJohn, That's what you function `public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items()` is doing but you can simplify it. I'll update my answer.