# mvc4 how can i create a dropdownlist in controller

Tags: controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I basically would like to know how can I create a list in a controller; for example I have this small list in a view

```
          @Html.DropDownList("postedstate", new SelectList(
     new List<Object>{
          new { Text = "West Virginia", Value = "WV"},
          new { Text = "Wyoming", Value = "WY"},
     }, "Value", "Text"))
```

How can I now create this same list inside a controller or a List object. I been searching and can not seem to figure it out any help would be great

Comment: Include a `SelectList` property in your view model or assign it to a `ViewBag` property. [This example might help explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676914/i-cant-get-a-dropdownlist-to-populate-from-table-ef-and-mvc4/25676985#25676985)

Comment: The answer is basically here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring/5688922#5688922