# EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

i Have a Model Class

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SelectListItem> CourseList { get; set; }
}
```

and the

```
public class StudentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and i try ti use it as

```
List<Student> sList =  db.Students.ToList();
```

and i am getting following error

```
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define     the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'SelectListItems' is based on type   'SelectListItem' that has no keys defined.
```

Please suggest where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be attempting to store `SelectListItem` in the database, as this is MVC specific concept. Instead create a custom entity class and use it instead;

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitle  { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> CourseList { get; set; }
}

public class StudentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i used selectitemlist because when i edit the student, i need a  listbox containg all courses, and i have to pre select the courses which student have already selected! i am just trying to retrieve through EF as of Now

and can you please let me know what table structure of above code which you mentioned, as i am confused how i will map CourseList in Student. @dotnetom

Comment: @KmrRaz In order to display the data from the database you should create a specific object, `StudentViewModel`. This is a specific object just for display purposes. In this have property with SelectListItems, which you can display in the View. In your controller method load the data of type `Student` and map it to `StudentViewModel`

Comment: Can you please let me know about the structure of StudentViewModel,  so that i will give it a try! i really appreciate if you will help me in this!

Comment: @KmrRaz, `StudentViewModel` should contain properties `int[] SelectedCourses` which will be bound to the ID of the selected courses, and `SelectList CourseList` which is the list of courses to display. Then in your view use `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCourses, Model.CourseList)`. [Refer this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676914/i-cant-get-a-dropdownlist-to-populate-from-table-ef-and-mvc4/25676985#25676985)

Comment: Thanks All, Your all helped me understanding the things well!

Answer (score 10):

Add `[NotMapped]` annotation to the LIST class

```
[NotMapped]
public List<SelectListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
```

`NotMapped` Code first convention dictates that every property that is of a supported data type is represented in the database. But this isn’t always the case in your applications. For example you might have a property in the Blog class that creates a code based on the Title and BloggerName fields. That property can be created dynamically and does not need to be stored. You can mark any properties that do not map to the database with the NotMapped annotation such as this BlogCode property.

```
[NotMapped] 
public string BlogCode 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return Title.Substring(0, 1) + ":" + BloggerName.Substring(0, 1); 
    } 
}
```

You can refer to the link here on [EF code first Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped)