# One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\n

Tags: c#, entity-framework, custom-errors

I am so confused. I am working on building a cascading dropdown and I am receiving the strangest error. I keep receiving the following error (it is a long one)-

*"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nAQB_MON.ViewModels.DeviceStatu: : EntityType 'DeviceStatu' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nAQB_MON.ViewModels.SelectListItem: : EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nDeviceStatus: EntityType: EntitySet 'DeviceStatus' is based on type 'DeviceStatu' that has no keys defined.\r\nSelectListItems: EntityType: EntitySet 'SelectListItems' is based on type 'SelectListItem' that has no keys defined.\r\n"}*

I have a Manufacturer table and a ManufacturerModel table. My cascading dropdown consists of a user selecting a manufacturer first and then corresponding model options would be available in the second dropdown. However I keep receiving the error when trying to load the dropdown.

I created my own ViewModel - ManufacturerModelContext

```
public class ManufacturerModelContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ManufacturerModel> ManufacturerModels { get; set; }
}
```

and I retrieve Manufacturers and Models with

```
//Populate the cascading dropdowns for manufacturer and model
    ManufacturerModelContext mm = new ManufacturerModelContext();
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetManufacturers()
    {

        var manufacturer = from a in mm.Manufacturers
                           select a.Manufacturer1;

        return Json(manufacturer.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    public JsonResult GetModelsByManufacturerID(string manufacturerId)
    {

        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(manufacturerId);

        var models = from a in mm.ManufacturerModels where a.ManufacturerID == Id select a;

        return Json(models);
    }
```

It fails at *Var manufacturer*. The strangest thing is that I don't even have and never did have a *AQB_MON.ViewModels.DeviceStatu*

Manufacturer Model

```
public partial class Manufacturer
{
    public Manufacturer()
    {
        this.ManufacturerModels = new HashSet<ManufacturerModel>();
    }

    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Manufacturer")]
    public string Manufacturer1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Manufacturer Description")]
    public string ManufacturerDescription { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE_CREATED { get; set; }
    public string CREATED_BY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATE_MODIFIED { get; set; }
    public string MODIFIED_BY { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ManufacturerModel> ManufacturerModels { get; set; }
```

ManufacturerModel Model

```
public partial class ManufacturerModel
{
    public ManufacturerModel()
    {
        this.Devices = new HashSet<Device>();
    }

    public int ManufacturerModelID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Manufacturer")]
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Model Description")]
    public string ModelDescription { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE_CREATED { get; set; }
    public string CREATED_BY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATE_MODIFIED { get; set; }
    public string MODIFIED_BY { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
```

Device Model

```
 public partial class Device
{
    public Device()
    {
        this.DeviceLocations = new HashSet<DeviceLocation>();
        this.DeviceLogs = new HashSet<DeviceLog>();
        this.DeviceStatus = new HashSet<DeviceStatu>();
    }


    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Device Type")]
    public int DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerModelID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Inventory Number")]
    public string InventoryNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Serial Number")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "State ID")]
    public string StateID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateReceived { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE_CREATED { get; set; }
    public string CREATED_BY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATE_MODIFIED { get; set; }
    public string MODIFIED_BY { get; set; }


    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public virtual ManufacturerModel ManufacturerModel { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DeviceLocation> DeviceLocations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DeviceLog> DeviceLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DeviceStatu> DeviceStatus { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is Manufacturer1? Showing the models may help.

Comment: I have updated my question with the Manufacturer Model and ManufactureModel Model

Comment: You've got a Device reference in your ManufacturerModel, but I don't see a DbSet. You need to either add a DbSet<Device> or add [NotMapped] to that navigation property.

Comment: I added 'public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }' to the ManufacturerModel model and then to the ManufacturerModelContext model however I still received the error.

Comment: Post the device model. Does it have navigation properties (like DeviceStatus)? You are getting a not key error so every entity in the chain needs to have a key that you define by convention, attribute or fluent api. All entities need a DbSet as well (or NotMapped).

Comment: As a test, you could comment out your Devices definition and see if it works with just those 2 models in the chain.

Comment: I updated the question with my Device Model

Comment: You need to understand how EF builds its models. Everything that you have a DbSet for is modeled. If those classes refer to other classes you need to add DbSets for them as well all the way down the chain. So you at a minimal need DbSets for DeviceType, DeviceLocation, DeviceLog and DeviceStatu and possibly more if they have children with classes in them.

Comment: "The strangest thing is that I don't even have and never did have a AQB_MON.ViewModels.DeviceStatu" -- Yes, you do have it. You also need to make sure that class has a key.

Comment: I just got rid of the missing key for AQB_MON.ViewModels.DeviceStatu by adding [Key] above its key in its model. However I am getting the same error for *AQB_MON.ViewModels.SelectListItem: : EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined.* - but I don't know where this is at

Comment: You should not try to store SelectListItem in the database. Add [NotMapped] above that property (look for ICollection<SelectListItem> MyListProperty in your models). As an alternative you could create a custom class that is stored in the database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091117/entitytype-selectlistitem-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entityty

Comment: Thank-you I was able to use [NotMapped] on them and got passed that error however I am trying to load this from the Index View for Create and a new error (never ending errors ugh) - CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file

Comment: That sounds like a database creation error. Now that your model is valid, EF is trying to create the database (see your connect string). I would create a separate question that shows your connection string, context, initializer and add a link from here.

Answer (score 1):

it could be what the error message says: EntityType 'DeviceStatu' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

it's hard to tell because you didn't post this entity's data model but it could be a naming issue

to be a key the field has to have the same name as the class like DeviceStatusId or use the [Key] data annotation above the field

Comment: I was able to get pass the error adding the `[Key]` annotation to my key field in my DeviceStatus model and then I received another error on my 'SelectListItem` that was resolved by adding `[NotMapped]` annotation on the SelectListItem elements. However this all resulted in leaving another error of _ CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.)_ This I haven't been able to resolve to date.

Comment: oh yeah, did you post , have a link to another question ?

Comment: I just posted my question under - CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.)